# mysql weird connection problem

Tags: mysql

I've a weird problem. I've mysql 5.1 installed on my ubuntu 9.04.

I've used it a long time (say 3 month) and everything was going right. Until i faced this really weird problem.

When i want to connect to a random database i get this message:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    1
Current database: test_cake

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server
```

It only happens with some databases, while others are totally usefull and healthy. After that, if i try to restart the server i get this.

```
shell> /etc/init.d/mysql restart
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                        cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
                                                                         [fail]
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                        cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permiso denegado
                                                                         [fail]
("permiso denegado" is "permission denied").
```

I don't know what to do. I change the /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid attributes  but still not working.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

do u have other instance of mysql on the same server ?
Mysqld is run as what user ?
who is the owner of /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ?

--
Regards,
Robert

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. I've just one instance of mysql running on my PC. It's a Ubuntu 9.04. The owner is "root" and the owner of /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid is "mysql"
I'll print the ls -l output for you:

santiago@santiago-desktop:~$ ls -la /var/run/mysqld/
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql root   80 2009-11-18 11:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root  root  940 2009-11-18 14:40 ..
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql   5 2009-11-18 11:26 mysqld.pid
srwxrwxrwx  1 mysql mysql   0 2009-11-18 11:26 mysqld.sock

Comment: hello
sorry for a huge postpone :D. If this issue is still valid please add 
at the beginning of /etc/init.d/mysql (mysql start-up script) 
"#!/bin/bash -x " as a replacement for "#!/bin/bash" I think that 
line 

"if [ -f "$pidfile" ] && ps `cat $pidfile` >/dev/null 2>&1; then ps_alive=1; fi"
produce errors. -x is a debug option for bash it will show you what the script is actually doing and it will give some clue where the problem is. 

--
Regards,
Robert